# MIPS: Trouble generating n-length string of byte characters

Tags: pointers, mips

I'm humiliated that I can't figure this out. I want a simple loop which will create a string out of a certain character by copying it into each byte address of the string. I've managed to do this without a loop, like so:

```
.text
main:
    lb $a1, char
    
    la $a0, str
    
    sb $a1, 0($a0)
    sb $a1, 1($a0)
    sb $a1, 2($a0)  
    sb $a1, 3($a0)
    sb $zero, 4($a0)
                        
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
.data
char: .byte 'i'
str: .space 10
```

This will give me 'iiii' as expected.

When I tried to implement this in a loop, the resulting string is blank.

```
.text
main:

    lbu $a1, o      # Load 'o' character
    li $t0, 10      # Create counter
    la $a0, str
loop:
    sb $a1, 0($a0)      # Store 'o' at first byte of $a0
    sub $t0, $t0, 1     # Decrement counter
    addi $a0, $a0, 1    # Increment pointer
    sb $zero, 0($a0)    # End string with $zero

    beqz $t0, end       # Branch to end if $t0 = 0
    j loop          # Loop
end:
    li $v0, 4       # Print resulting string
    syscall

.data
o: .byte 'o'
str: .space 11
```

I can't seem to debug this.  I must be misunderstanding how to increment the pointer, or how to store bytes properly. Please forgive my confusion. I come begging for advice after banging my head against a wall for many hours.

Comment: You need to set `$a0` back to the start of the string to print it -- currently it points at the end, so prints nothing.

Comment: @ChrisDodd You are a gentleman and a scholar. Such a simple detail to neglect. So, one has to keep track of iterations in order to "rewind" the pointer. Thank you, sir!

Comment: You can also just reload it with `la $a0, str`